# Why was this question deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444447/base-64-code-error-when-trying-to-insert-to-database) was deleted by a moderator (10k+ only, sorry).

My question is why? It was in full progress, was a valid question, and did not have a good  answer yet. It *is* unsolvable with what detail the OP currently has in there, but that's not a reason to delete something, is it.

Did the OP request its deletion?

Comment: Strange indeed.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the OP could delete it on his own as long as there weren't useful answers.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Only if there is one answer AND the answer doesn't have an upvote.

Comment: And this one had two answers, each negatively scored, each with (sympathy) upvotes.

Comment: Yes, the [OP requested the deletion, as ProblematicTitleException stated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115501/140951), I was the one that deleted it.  I'd post an answer, but it's described well-enough there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was deleted at the OP's request. Here's what his flag says:

> I want this thread to get deleted, the problem was something totally other than the question says

It wasn't very a good question anyways; probably would've been closed as 'too localized'.

Comment: ahhh, okay. Thanks. And no, it wasn't a great question to begin with - just not necessarily one deserving deletion. (You can accept an answer in 6 minutes)